# Array of generic classes and subclassing

Tags: arrays, swift, generics, inheritance

I'm having trouble wrapping my head around generics. What I want is to have an array of generic classes, each with it's own associated type, and call a function accordingly. It would look something like this:

```
class SomeGenericClass<U> {
    func addCallback(callback: (U)->() ) { ... }
}

var array: [SomeGenericClass] // compile error
```

The last line yields an error, so I found that I needed to have a superclass. I tried something like this:

```
class SuperClass {
    func addCallback<V>(callback: (V)->() ) { ... }
}

class SomeGenericClass<U> {
    func addCallback<V: U>(callback: (V)->() ) { ... } // compile error
}

var array: [SuperClass] // no compile error
```

This yields the error `Type 'V' constrained to non-protocol, non-class type 'U'`.

Basically I want to be able to do:

```
array.append(SomeGenericClass<UIImage>()) // array[0]
array.append(SomeGenericClass<Int>()) // array[1]

// Since array[0] is effectively of type SomeGenericClass<UIImage>, the compiler should understand that the close added if of type (UIImage)->(), and therefore that value is of type UIImage
array[0].addCallback { value in
   someImageView.image = value
}
```

Is using a superclass the right approach in this case? How should it be implemented?

Comment: Thanks for including your final goal. That's not possible. `value` must have a single type, known at compile time. The fact that you don't have to write down the type doesn't mean the compiler doesn't have to know what it is. What line of code would you write next that *uses* `value`, given that you know nothing about what type it is? Try to write a callback block that actually works with this, and does something more than call `print(value)`, remembering I can change `array[0]` to anything I want, and your code still has to work.

Comment: The best way to get your head around generics is to start with concrete code that has duplication. Then work out how to remove the duplication using generics. Starting with generics, and then trying to find how you would use them is almost always going to get you into a corner. So in a world without generics, where you just had to duplicate the code for every type, what would you write here?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I update the code of what I want a little bit. Is that not possible at all? What would we a possible workaround?

Comment: I think it's important to note also that my array is constant, it's defined in a lazy var and will not change — and actually, it's a dictionary. Therefore, when I access an element, I know for sure what type it will be. Maybe we can make use of that, and change the structure type?

Comment: But if `array[0]` element is `SomeGenericClass<Int>` then why would you need to do `someImageView.image = value`. The `value` in this case would be of type `Int`.

Comment: That's the thing, I know that array[0] is `SomeGenericClass<UIImage>` because it's a constant lazy var. My array is defined in code and won't change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I worked around this problem by storing my array members in their own variable. That is, instead of defining my array like:

```
lazy var array: [SuperClass] = [
    SomeGenericClass<UIImage>(),
    SomeGenericClass<Int>(),
    //etc...
]
```

I defined it this way:

```
lazy var genericFirst: SomeGenericClass<UIImage> = SomeGenericClass<UIImage>()
lazy var genericSecond: SomeGenericClass<Int> = SomeGenericClass<Int>()
// etc...

lazy var array: [SuperClass] = [
    genericFirst,
    genericSecond,
    //etc...
]
```

This way, I can access the generics I want like this:

```
genericFirst.addCallback { value in
    // value is indeed of type UIImage
    someImageView.image = value
}
```

Comment: What is the purpose of `array` here? What code consumes it? (Depending on your problem, this could be a completely correct solution, so I'm not certain what you mean when you say it's not proper. That said, I don't understand why these are lazy. That looks very wasteful here.)

Comment: This array stores a list a view, it's a way of organizing a long scrollview that acts as a form, with different cells and controls, and to have a common way to fill the views with values from an input object, and listen for the changes of these controls.

Comment: ok; if these are UIViews and you're just going to loop over them and do something like `addSubview` on them to get them into the scrollview, then your solution is ideal, and exactly how you should write it (I've built systems like this for years). Properties for the things you need direct access to, and an array to hold everything. Essentially identical to how a storyboard is full of views, and the ones you want specific access to you create an IBOutlet property for.

Comment: Glad to hear that! I accepted the answer then. Thank you!